# Create many relationships from CSV on Neo4j is very slow, how to resolve this?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I try to move some RDB records into Neo4j. There is a relation table on MySQL. I would like to change this into relationships on Neo4j.

I created two nodes, like following.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM 'file:///transactions.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Tran {
  key_from: line.key
});

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM 'file:///master.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Master {
  key_to: line.key
  , value: line.value
});
```

Import finished very quickly. `Tran` has 20,000 records. `Master` has 270,000 records. Then I tried to import relation csv file.

I tried two queries. But, both of them never finished. There are 5,000 relations, but there are some relations should be matched, rest of them will not match.

Try1:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM 'file:///relation.csv' AS line
OPTIONAL MATCH (t:Tran { key_from: line.key_from })
OPTIONAL MATCH (m:Master { key_to: line.key_to })
CREATE (t)-[r:CONV]->(m);
```

Try2:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM 'file:///relation.csv' AS line
WITH line.key_from AS key_from, 
     line.key_to AS key_to
MERGE (t:Tran { key_from: key_from })
MERGE (m:Master { key_to: key_to })
MERGE (t)-[r:CONV]->(m);
```

Would you tell me best practice ?

Comment: Create index on :Tran(key_from)
Create index on :Master(key_to)

Comment: @DaveFauth Bingo! After created indexes, importing relations finished very quickly. Please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @hiropon did you RedisGraph? Due to its internal matrix based implementation, loading many relationships is pretty efficient